# Arduino serial coming up with weird characters

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-ide

I am trying to create a basic snake game using the arduino UNO along with the MAX72XX module, the LCD module and the analog joystick module. I am wanting to program my program using object orientated programming. I have no experience with C++ so I am struggling quite a bit to understand why the serial comes up with unusual characters whenever I am trying to print off variable values. The serial is able to print text, but whenever I try to print variable values the unusual characters come up. I had tried changing the baud to a higher one and that makes no difference. The two variables that I am trying to print off both have an integer data type. I have tried using `Serial.write`, `Serial.print` and `Serial.println`, none of these seem to work. Here is the code if it helps solve the problem:

```
#include "LedControl.h"
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>
LedControl lc=LedControl(12,10,11,1);
LiquidCrystal lcd(8, 13, 3, 5, 6, 7);


class Snake_body
{


  public:

    int following_direction;
    int x;
    int y;
    int previous_x;
    int previous_y;
    bool enabled;
    Snake_body()
    {
      this->enabled = false;
    }

    void configure(int x_value, int y_value)
    {
      this->enabled = true;
      this->following_direction = 1;
      this->x = x_value;
      this->y = y_value;
      this->previous_y = y_value;
      this->previous_x = x_value;  
    }

};


class Power_up
{
  private:

  public:
    virtual void init() 
    {
      this->x = 0;
      this->y = 0;
    }

    int x;
    int y;
};

Snake_body *snake[64];//this is the snake array that contains the snake objects

int snakes_length;


Power_up *power_up;//define the power up object

int score;

void setup() {

  Serial.begin(9600);


  lcd.begin(16, 2);

  snakes_length = 1;

  for(int z = 1; z < 64; z++)
  {
    snake[z] = new Snake_body();//create 63 un-enabled snake objects  
  }

  snake[0] = new Snake_body();//the 1st snake object is defined
  snake[0]->configure(0,0);//here it is initialised 
  power_up = new Power_up();//create the power_up object

  lc.shutdown(0,false);
  lc.setIntensity(0,8);
  lc.clearDisplay(0);
  lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
  score = 0;
  lcd.print("score: ");
  lcd.setCursor(6, 0);
  lcd.print(score);
  pinMode(2, INPUT);
  digitalWrite(2, HIGH);

  power_up->x = random(0, 8);
  power_up->y = random(0, 8);
}

int snake_direction;


void loop() 
{
  int x_axis = analogRead(A0);
  int y_axis = analogRead(A1);
  int switcher = digitalRead(2);


   if(x_axis <= 400) //&& x < 7)//each of the if statements are for the direction of the snake head (snake[0])
   {
     snake[0]->following_direction = 0;
     //x += 1;
     //Serial->println("right");
   }


   else if(x_axis >= 600) //&& x > 0)
   {
     snake[0]->following_direction = 1;
     //x -= 1;
     //Serial->println("left");
   }


   else if(y_axis <= 400) //&& y > 0)
   {
     snake[0]->following_direction = 2;
     //y -= 1;
     //Serial->println("up");
   }


   else if(y_axis >= 600) //&& y < 7)
   {
     snake[0]->following_direction = 3;
     //y += 1;
     //Serial->println("down");
   }





  if(snake[0]->following_direction == 0 && snake[0]->x < 7)//used for snake movement
  {
    snake[0]->previous_x = snake[0]->x;
    snake[0]->x += 1;
  }

  else if(snake[0]->following_direction == 1 && snake[0]->x > 0)//used for snake movement
  {
    snake[0]->previous_x = snake[0]->x;
    snake[0]->x -= 1;
  }

  else if(snake[0]->following_direction == 2 && snake[0]->y > 0)//used for snake movement
  {
    snake[0]->previous_y = snake[0]->y;
    snake[0]->y -= 1;
  }

  else if(snake[0]->following_direction == 3 && snake[0]->y < 7)//used for snake movement
  {
    snake[0]->previous_y = snake[0]->y;
    snake[0]->y += 1;
  }


  if(snake[0]->x == power_up->x && snake[0]->y == power_up->y)//used for collision with power up
  {
    score += 1;
    lcd.setCursor(6,0);
    lcd.print(score);

    power_up->x = random(0, 8);
    power_up->y = random(0, 8);


    for(int j = 0; j < 64; j++)
    {
      if(snake[j]->enabled == false)//enables the next un-enabled snake object in the array
      {
         //Serial.println(true);
         Snake_body *snake[j];

         //next_snake_body = new Snake_body();
         //Snake_body next_snake_body;
         snake[j] = new Snake_body();
         snake[j]->configure(snake[j-1]->previous_x, snake[j-1]->previous_y);
         //Serial.print("x: " + snake[j-1]->previous_x);
         //Serial.print("y: " + snake[j-1]->previous_y);
         snake[j]->following_direction = NULL;
         break;
      }
    }
  }


  for(int i = 1; i < 64; i++)
  {
    if(snake[i]->enabled == true)//updates each snake object in the array
    {

      snake[i]->x = snake[i-1]->previous_x;
      snake[i]->y = snake[i-1]->previous_y;    
    }
  }


  lc.setLed(0,power_up->x,power_up->y,true);//draws the power up
  for(int w = 0; w < 64; w++)
  {
    if(snake[w]->enabled == true)//draws each snake object that is enabled
    {
      Serial.print("x: " + snake[w]->x);
      Serial.print("y: " + snake[w]->y);
      lc.setLed(0,snake[w]->x,snake[w]->y,true);  
    }
  }

  /*Serial->print("x: ");
  Serial->print(snake->x);
  Serial->println();

  Serial->print("y: ");
  Serial->print(snake->y);
  Serial->println();*/



  delay(100); 

  lc.clearDisplay(0);
}
```

the weird characters that show up are characters like this:
[image]

with the follow picture `y` is just simply text to show which axis it is, the weird characters are the integer y axis value of the snake object that is being looked at.

Comment: Make a copy of your sketch and cut out everything but printing one text message and one variable value. Do you still have a problem? Add back a little bit at a time until the problem reappears. What you just added back is the cause.

Comment: everything can be important information when debugging code, including the weird characters ... please add the weird character printout to your post

Comment: There are some weird statements in the code, like the line `Snake_body *snake[j];`.. this does nothing and looks like a variable declaration, I'd remove that. Also in the beginning you `snake[z] = new Snake_body();` but don't initialize the values (like `y`, `x`)  in them via a constructor or `initialize()` function -- those will be random then and possibly garbage. You calso call `Serial->print(snake->x);` but `snake` is an 64-element array of `Snake` pointers, so that won't work. You need an index here.

Comment: Oh, and you also have a memory leak when you `snake[j] = new Snake_body();`. There already is a `Snake_body` element in there and you've overwritten the pointer to it with a newly allocated object without `delete`-ing the previous on -- reevaluate whether you really need to allocate a new object here of want to modify the existing one. If the latter, cleanup the memory.

Comment: You are using quite a bit of dynamic memory allocation. Note that this is a bad idea on an Arduino in 99% of cases. You can easily fill up all RAM without knowing beforehand and even when you correctly delete objects, that aren't needed anymore, you are getting your heap fragmented

Comment: @MaximilianGerhardt `Serial->print(snake->x);` was something I comment out and don't need anymore in my code. I forgot to take it out. Additionally, each object that I have created is needed because these are the body parts of the snake. Also, I am not very experienced with C++, so it took along time to get this code to where it is now.

Comment: @chrisl All the snake objects are needed, each time a new one is defined this is another part of the snake

Comment: Sure every part is needed, but you're initially filling all 64 elements of the array with `new Snake_body` objects and then overwrite the pointer to that object with `snake[j] = new Snake_body();` i.e. another `Snake_body` object, that's a memory leak (https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/memory-leak-in-c-and-how-to-avoid-it/). You should be able to do this with all static allocation and no `new` / dynamic memory, just a static array of 64 `Snake_body` objects.

Comment: @MaximilianGerhardt Ok, I now see where you are going with this. What the for loop in setup does is that it just puts a Snake_body object in each space in the array and then, once the power up is touched the for loop will go through the snake array until an object which has not been enabled is found and then that object will then be configured and initialised.

Comment: @MaximilianGerhardt look at the code (I have commented what each part of the code does)

Comment: @jsotola the characters always change each time but I have posted an example above in the question of what similar characters come up.

Comment: @MaximilianGerhardt the problem is that I needed to do this because I needed something comparable so that I could find an empty space in the array. Do you know how I could possibly find an empty space in the array without having to have a RAM memory leak

Comment: If you want to mark an `empty` space, why not make this a member in your field element structure? Then you can have an always-there 64 field array with just different attributes in them. Maybe it's better to think of the play field as generic tiles which have attributes like whether a snake part is on them or a powerup, and then save extra info like the head and teal of the snake to move it / expand it.

Comment: @MaximilianGerhardt I am not 100% clear of what you said.

Comment: @MaximilianGerhardt Would it potentially work if each object at the beginning is null except `snake[0]`. Then to find an empty object you would go through the array until you find an element in the array with a NULL value then this element with a null value becomes an object. Could that potentially work